# ubuntu 11.04 server no gui jungledisc server

Tags: backup, ubuntu-11.04, jungledisk

i am attempting to setup jungle disc server on ubuntu linux on the rackspace cloud server setup. this box has ubuntu linux 11.04 OS, nginx webserver, mysql db, and php. I ran through this setup to http://support.jungledisk.com/forums/61798-user-guide-jungle-disk-server-edition to get the server component working which I have verified is running using the top command, however I can not connect the client.

according to the guide I downloaded and installed the server client to my desktop and I attempted to connect via logging into my account, however, the server will not show up.

also, my server still says pending under subscriptions and purchases.

I can't find anything on this issue? thoughts?

**Updates**

```
log file:
09:23:51 AM: Warning Details (Jungle Disk Server Edition 3.16 Linux Console x64) 
------------------------ 
Exception thrown 
Exception Code: xConnectFailed (4) 
Time: 10/08/2011 09:23:51 AM (GMT-7) 
Detailed Message: HTTP connection failed: couldn't connect to host [127.0.0.1:10909] 
Error Location: JungleHTTP.cpp:986

09:23:51 AM: Warning Details (Jungle Disk Server Edition 3.16 Linux Console x64) 
------------------------ 
Exception thrown 
Exception Code: xServiceTransport (109) 
Time: 10/08/2011 09:23:51 AM (GMT-7) 
Detailed Message: Transport error during Ping 
Error Location: JXRTransport.cpp:32 
-- Inner Exception: -- 
Exception Code: xConnectFailed (4) 
Time: 10/08/2011 09:23:51 AM (GMT-7) 
Detailed Message: HTTP connection failed: couldn't connect to host [127.0.0.1:10909] 
Error Location: JungleHTTP.cpp:986

09:23:51 AM: Jungle Disk Server Edition has not been configured. 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP INFO: About to connect() to s3.amazonaws.com port 80 (#0) 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP INFO: Trying 72.21.214.38... 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP INFO: connected 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP INFO: Connected to s3.amazonaws.com (72.21.214.38) port 80 (#0) 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP OUT: GET /onlinecheck/check.txt HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: Jungle Disk Server Edition HTTP/86 
Host: s3.amazonaws.com 
Accept: */* 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: x-amz-id-2: aFIiBnOvAIMEIaZdPpM5DM8fb0gqXTf/EN+MWXsYdPIqj7OGI3mQ5f/4sJKWQRz9 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: x-amz-request-id: B0E812B46AD6AFED 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: Date: Sat, 08 Oct 2011 16:23:52 GMT 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: Content-Disposition: file; filename=check.txt 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: Last-Modified: Fri, 09 May 2008 20:44:25 GMT 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: ETag: "e0aa021e21dddbd6d8cecec71e9cf564" 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: Accept-Ranges: bytes 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: Content-Type: text/plain 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: Content-Length: 2 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: Server: AmazonS3 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP IN: 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP INFO: Connection #0 to host s3.amazonaws.com left intact 
09:23:51 AM: HTTP INFO: Closing connection #0
```

The server is now reporting active.  I have found these links: 
http://support.jungledisk.com/entries/20553-command-line-integration-updated
http://support.jungledisk.com/entries/19061-jungle-disk-configuration-files

any walkthroughs on how to set this up? can you connect to this disc form your workgroup computer i.e. my main workstation too?

**Update**

I am now downloading a full copy of ubuntu server to set up in vmware to try this a little differently

Comment: You pay for it so I would call their support.

Comment: I already started a thread with them, but thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely mistake to make here (I did so myself!) is copying `junglediskserver-license-EXAMPLE.xml` to /etc/jungledisk and forgetting rename it to `junglediskserver-license.xml`